# Would it be legal for bookmakers to take bets on someone being assassinated?

Tags: united-kingdom, murder

Background: My colleague just told me that he reckons Donald Trump's presidency is most likely to end in assassination. My first thought was: "Why not put money on it then?"; my second thought was "Would that be legal?".

From the bookmaker's point of view, taking such a bet would be stupid: if a person stands to win £100,000 from Trump being assassinated, it would give them motivation to pay someone up to that figure to carry out the killing. Further than that, I wonder whether giving someone motivation to kill someone could legally count as inciting someone to murder, which is illegal. Hence why I wonder whether it would be legal for a bookmaker to take such a bet.

As I'm from the UK, I'm mainly interested from the UK legal perspective, but any other international perspective is welcome.

Comment: Just for the sake of interest, [The Pale Horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pale_Horse) by Agatha Christie, is about a business that makes money by betting on people's deaths.

Comment: Actually, in that book people would bet say £10,000 that their rich uncle will _not_ die, and then someone let's say changes the odds in their favour and makes sure that the person betting loses their bet. So you lose £10,000 and also your rich uncle - but the inheritance would be a bit of consolation.

Comment: [Assassination market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_market)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general it is illegal to gamble on life.  However, you *might* not even need to go to a bookmaker: A contract that pays money upon the death of a specific person is known commercially as "life insurance."

In order to avoid the moral hazard (or reality) of creating a contract killing market, [it has long been illegal to trade life insurance with any person or entity who does not have an **"insurable interest"** in the insured](https://www.lexisnexis.com/legalnewsroom/insurance/b/insurance-coverage/archive/2011/09/30/wager-on-life-void-life-insurance-requires-insurable-interest-stoli-stranger-originated-gambler-void-ab-initio.aspx).  (See also: [The Insurable Interest Requirement for Life Insurance](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/579b/65324acd2569bb933fbdb71f128d4857648d.pdf), by Peter Swisher, who also has [a good review of laws and regulations surrounding exceptions to the rule like viaticals and STOLI](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8b81/f2fcda8ad29c7b31f02d757a401e71e8ff3e.pdf).  Further reading on the subject [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+viaticals+avoid+insured+interest+requirement).)

I don't know if it has been tested, but I think anyone could *argue* that they would face a significant financial loss if the U.S. President were killed or died in office: [the stock markets plunged on JFK's assassination](http://www.usatoday.com/story/money/markets/2013/11/21/stock-market-reaction-to-jfk-assassination/3662171/).  Therefore, it *could* be both legal and possible for anyone to buy life insurance on the U.S. President.

(Note that, in the U.S., the disputes about third-party life insurance have revolved for generations around the tax benefits associated with insurance premiums and benefits.  See [corporate-owned life insurance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate-owned_life_insurance) (COLI), a.k.a. "janitor's insurance.")